# Spring @AspectJ не вызывает совет (pointcut работает)

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, aop

Пытаюсь разобраться с АОП в Spring. Простой совет в @AspectJ не вызывается.
Прокси создается, информация об аспекте присутствует в прокси, но совет не вызывается.
Idea Intellij также распознает аспект.
Пробовала как аннотации, так и xml.  На сегодняшний момент код в аннотации:

```
@Aspect    
public class TavleiEventPublisher {

    @Before("execution(* TavleiServerController.beginTurn(..))")
    public void beginTurn(){
        throw new RuntimeException("Begin Turn Advise");
    }

    public TavleiEventPublisher() {
    }       
}
```

spring.xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy  />
    <context:component-scan base-package="gamecontrol"/>

    <bean id="controllerManager" class="gamecontrol.TavleiServerController" init-method="init"/>
    <bean id="eventListener" class="model.event.EventListener"/>

    <!-- Aspect for TavleiControllers-->
    <bean id="tavleiEventPublisher" class="gamecontrol.TavleiEventPublisher"/>

</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Скриншот с данными debug
[image: Картинка с данными debug]
Скриншот с распознаванием Intellij аспекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD:**
Проблема была, в том что внутренние вызовы методов не отлавливаются.
Т.е. beginTurn() вызывался внутри другого метода (startGame) того же объекта. Если вызывать beginTurn() напрямую из другого объекта, вызов отлавливается.

Альтернативные решения описаны здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780757/spring-aop-logging-and-nested-methods
Одно из решений - включать AspectJ для поддержки aop или добавлять self к внутренним вызовам...

Спасибо!

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: Спасибо. Но я вроде представила информацию в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что аспекты и бины находятся в разных контекстах. Аспекты находят в AplicationContext, а бины(контроллеры) в WebApplicationContext. AspectJ autoproxy нужно включить в WebApplicationContext.

Comment: Я пока еще не перевела на spring MVC. Контроллер ли Аспект находились в том же контексте.